# Install Tensorflow pip wheel without internet

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard, bazel

I do not have internet access on my linux computer therefore I installed TF from source by following [TensorFlow Get Started](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/get_started/os_setup.html#installing-from-sources).
I ran into a few trouble to build trainer_example due to the lack of internet connection hopefully someone from tensorflow helped me through it by creating local repositories for re2, gemmlowp, jpegsrc v9a, libpng and six and modifying WORKSPACE accordingly.
When I try to bazel build pip_package to create the wheel then I think I run into the same problem but :

-the list of repositories is insanely long (to manually install each of them) even if they seem to be mostly part of PolymerElements

Is there an easy workaround ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are happy to create a PIP package **without TensorBoard**, you should be able to avoid rewriting the Polymer dependencies by removing [this line](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/03b5bef1ddbb5841aaf059a8b77267becbe8ea21/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/BUILD#L29) (`"//tensorflow/tensorbaord"` in the `build_pip_package` dependencies) from `tensorflow/tools/pip_package/BUILD`.

Comment: Is there a plan to build an all-in version meaning one that even though it would be pretty big could be installed locally without doing all this fooling around ?

Comment: Thanks for the workaround!!! however it is a pity not to have tensorboard ! I downloaded all the dependencies myself and modified the paths but I did not pay attention to the versions of the different libraries and some of the files bazel cannot reach resulting in making the compilation fail.

Comment: I succeeded in building it thanks to you however I am working on getting all the sources to make tensorboard work also. However the gpu support build with bazel failed for no reason !

Comment: @jean Could you share your installation steps? I am trying to install tensorflow without internet too. I downloaded https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.8.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl and then use pip install --upgrade ./tensorflow-0.8.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl but got errors.

Comment: Once you have downloaded  the python wheel that corresponds to your install (from another computer that does have internet access) you should be fine with a simple pip install ./tensorflow_wheel_linux_x86_64.whl. No need to add --upgrade (besides it should not work as you do not have internet access). It worked for me at least. Make sure you follow through the steps on the tensorflow website. This thread is for installing FROM SOURCES which is a real pain in the ass if you do not have internet as you have to manually get around 80 dependencies (most of them coming from tensorboard).

Comment: If you insist on installing from sources go to bazel repository issues they are very helpful with stuff like that.